# Ebeans where columnA equals columnB in same table

Tags: java, ebean

I have a table that, amongst other things, has two columns of type Long. In my query, i want to return rows where column A (type long) equals column B (type long). 
I would like to do this without writing raw sql, and instead use the much nicer method chaining.

So far i've always had a value to compare the column against, which i can pass in, such as

```
.eq("columnA", 5L)
```

However, I can't seem to find any method for something like

```
.eq("columnA", "columnB")
```

I feel like this should be a fairly standard kind of search to do (at least not rare). Does anyone out there know how I could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.raw("columnA = columnB") should work.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I'll give it a go this evening!

Comment: worked perfectly. sorry for the delay in accepting the answer!