# EBean inner join on the same table

Tags: java, sql-server, orm, ebean, playframework-2.6

I need to execute an inner join on the same table. Below is the raw query I am currently executing.

```
String tagValueRowsSQL = "SELECT itv1.ItemTagValueID,itv1.FkItemID," +
            "itv1.FkTagID,itv1.TagIndex,itv1.ValueIndex,itv1.Value,itv1.LastUpdateDateTime" +
            " FROM tag.ItemTagValue itv1" +
            " INNER JOIN tag.ItemTagValue itv2" +
            " on itv1.fkTagID=" + tagIDsAndValues.get(LOCATION_STORE_CONFIG_TAG_NAME).getTagID() +
            " and itv1.Value=" + storeId +
            " and itv2.fkTagID = " + tagIDsAndValues.get(SENSOR_TYPE_TAG_NAME).getTagID() +
            " and itv2.Value=" + sensorType;
    RawSql rawSqlForSensorsInStoreAndOfType = RawSqlBuilder.parse(tagValueRowsSQL)
            .columnMapping("itv1.ItemTagValueID", "ItemTagValueID")
            .columnMapping("itv1.FkItemID", "FkItemID")
            .columnMapping("itv1.FkTagID", "FkTagID")
            .columnMapping("itv1.TagIndex", "TagIndex")
            .columnMapping("itv1.ValueIndex", "ValueIndex")
            .columnMapping("itv1.Value", "Value")
            .columnMapping("itv1.LastUpdateDateTime", "LastUpdateDateTime")
            .create();
    Query<ItemTagValueModel> query = Ebean.find(ItemTagValueModel.class);
    List<ItemTagValueModel> sensorsTagValueData = query.setRawSql(rawSqlForSensorsInStoreAndOfType).findList();
```

Executing the above using RawSQL seems pretty clumsy. How can I execute the above without using RawSQL? I checked this question [Ebeans where columnA equals columnB in same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319922/ebeans-where-columna-equals-columnb-in-same-table) but I'm not sure how to apply that answer to my situation. Any help would be much appreciated.